# Sum column values using filter with selected values only in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a data set as:

```
Code        | Value0  |  Value1    | Value2     |
------------| --------|----------- | -----------|
CAR         | 44000   | 5.0        | 2          |
CBB         | 1000    | 0.89       | 9          |
CC          | 1450    | 1.56       | 5          |
CIVG        | 21000   | 0.786      | 19         |
CIVR        | 7000    | 134.6      | 15         |
CBB         | 21000   | 440        | 39         |
CC          | 14000   | 16.78      | 35         |
CIVG        | 100     | 98.56      | 9          |
CIVR        | 45000   | 15         | 54         |
```

I want to aggreagate based on column `code`, using the filter that  `Only those rows should be summed which have value0 greater than 10000`. However, this exception or filter should only apply to codes `CIVG and CIVR`. This filter will not apply to the other codes.

The query that I have been able to figure out:

```
select code , 
       count(1) filter (where value0 > 10000 ) as funt,
       count(1) ount,
       sum(value2) filter (where value0 > 10000 ) "farc" ,
       sum(value2) "oarc"
from table 
group by code
order by code;
```

Using which, I get the below result:

```
    Code    | funt |  ount   |   farc      |    oarc  |
------------| -----|---------| ------------|----------|
CAR         | 1    | 1       | 2           |   2      |
CBB         | 1    | 2       | 39          |   48     |
CC          | 1    | 2       | 35          |   40     |
CIVG        | 1    | 2       | 19          |   28     |
CIVR        | 1    | 2       | 54          |   69     |
```

What I want is that the variables apart from `CIVG` and `CIVR`, should not have the filter apply to them, which would give the result something like:

```
    Code    | funt |   farc      
------------| -----|---------
CAR         | 1    | 2        
CBB         | 2    | 48         
CC          | 2    | 40       
CIVG        | 1    | 19     
CIVR        | 1    | 54
```

Basically, the filter only works for the value that we provide and rest of the data follows the usual logic of summary. Is this possible using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a condition to the `filter`:

```
select code , 
       count(1) filter (where value0 > 10000 or code not in ('CIVG', 'CIVR')) as funt,
       count(1) ount,
       sum(value2) filter (where value0 > 10000 or code not in ('CIVG', 'CIVR')) "farc" ,
       sum(value2) "oarc"
from table 
group by code
order by code;
```

Comment: Thank you! I got a little confused with how where clause worked in the filter function. This gave me exactly what I wanted!